# Как получить scrollTop в React?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть contextMenu которое абсолютно спозиционированна. При клике правой кнопкой мыши на определенные компоненты. Меню должна вызываться там же где произошел клик мыши. Но дело в том что e.pageY при прокрутки страницы в низ выдает значение e.clienY . Вот я и думаю прибавить то что проскролилось к e.pageY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается ответ был в том что у body и html стояло в css height и width 100% и из за этого js не могла посчитать высоту